# Is closed subspace (open subspace) of a sequential space sequential?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

> A topological space is called a sequential space if a set $A ⊂ X$ is
>   closed if and only if together with any sequence it contains all its
>   limits.

Is every **open subspace** of a sequential space, still a sequential space? or every **closed subspace** of a sequential space, still a sequential space?

Comment: Can you show that a sequentially closed subset of a sequentially closed subspace is sequentially closed in the original space? What about the same condition for sequentially open sets? Once you know this, it should be easy to show that closed (open) subspace of a [sequential space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) is sequential.

Answer (score 3):

I will freely use [these definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Definitions).

Let $X$ be a sequential space, and suppose that $F$ is a closed subspace of $X$. Let $A$ be a sequentially closed subset of $F$. Suppose that $\sigma$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to some point $x\in X$; $\sigma$ is a sequence in $F$, and $F$ is closed in $X$, so $x\in F$, and since $A$ is sequentially closed in $F$, it follows that $x\in A$. Thus, $A$ is sequentially closed in $X$ as well as in $F$, and since $X$ is sequential, $A$ is closed in $X$. But $A\subseteq F$, so $A=A\cap F$, and therefore $A$ is closed in $F$. This shows that every sequentially closed subset of $F$ is closed in $F$ and hence that $F$ is sequentially closed.

Now suppose that $U$ is an open subspace of $X$, and let $V$ be a sequentially open subset of $U$. Let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ be any sequence in $X$ converging to some $x\in V$; $x\in U$, which is open in $X$, so $\sigma$ is eventually in $U$, i.e., there is an $m\in\omega$ such that $x_n\in U$ for each $n\ge m$. Then $\sigma'=\langle x_n:n\ge m\rangle$ is a sequence in $U$ converging to $x\in V$, and $V$ is sequentially open in $U$, so $\sigma'$ is eventually in $V$: there is an $m'\ge m$ such that $x_n\in V$ for each $n\ge m'$. Thus, $\sigma$ is eventually in $V$, and $V$ is therefore sequentially open in $X$ as well as in $U$. Finally, $X$ is sequential, so $V$ is actually open in $X$. Finally, $V=V\cap U$, so $V$ is open in $U$, and it follows that $U$ is sequential.